# Is it possible to replace the %d

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int M1[5][5], M2[10][3];
    int i, j, k = 1, m, n;
    int x, y, z, l = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of row ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Enter number of columns";
    cin >> n;
    printf("\nEnter the elements of the matrix :\n");

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf ("%d", &M1[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

I want to replace the 'scanf' with 'cin' but is it possible to replace the '%d' by something else and still keeping the data?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `std::cin >> M1[i][j];` will do...

Comment: I also don't understand the question.

Comment: Of course you can use `"%i"` for the same result.

Comment: i was trying to replace the "scanf"  with "cin>>"...but if i replace it with "cin>>",  i get error with the "%d"..thats why i wanted to ask if there is a way to use the "%d" with "cin>>".

Comment: If you have problems, make a [mcve] of the code that fails, along with the error message.  BTW, a *minimal* example won't need any of those arrays; it doesn't need much more than `#include <iostream` and `int main() { int i; std::cin >> i; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you no longer need `%d`, though. Just use `cin`:

```
std::cin >> M1[i][j];
```